# Run a php script through terminal in prestashop

Tags: migration, prestashop-1.7

For now, we doing the site migration from Joomla to Prestashop. we created a PHP migration script to migrate all the categories, products, variant and combination. This script working fine with categories, products and variants. But while adding the combination, script goes to 504 gateway error, to fix this issue we increased the execution time and memory limit but its not working. So we tried to run our migration script through the terminal, but we don't know how to configure our script to run in the terminal. Kindly advice us.